# How to call a controller action in Grails 3 in Grails Console?

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails3

I have been trying to call a controller action in Grails 3 from the console. So far I have been able to inject the controller instance in my Grails console using the following code but not able to fire off the action.

```
import grails.util.Holders

def c = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("com.example.TestController")

c.index()  // this doesn't work
```

Comment: what class is the `c` of?

Comment: it's com.example.TestController